# Пару предложений или паре предложений?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Как корректно сказать: **ответ в паре предложений** или **ответ в пару предложений**? Допустимы ли оба варианта?

Comment: Чтобы дать конкретный ответ, нужно видеть полное предложение.

Answer (score 1):

По части нормативности не вижу большой разницы. Контекста не хватает. "Ответ - в чем?" или "ответ - куда?"?

В любом случае лучше "***[уложите] ответ в два предложения***" или "***[сформулировал] ответ в двух предложениях***". А еще лучше: "ответить в два предложения". Но тут, повторюсь, контекст нужно знать.

"Пара" в разговорной речи может означать "несколько", но это не самый высокий стиль.